Issue with Embedding Chatflow and Passing Parameters to Flowise
I've encountered an issue while trying to embed the Flowise chat within a website and pass parameters via chatflowConfig to the flow, specifically to override the "url" for the API node. Unfortunately, none of the parameters I tested seem to work, and it appears the flow is completely ignoring them.
Here is the code snippet I'm using:
<script type="module">
  import Chatbot from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flowise-embed/dist/web.js';
  Chatbot.init({
    chatflowid: "bc7495d5-aec7-4067-a413-b57471482ea7",
    apiHost: "http://84.140.44.51:5777",
    chatflowConfig: {
      url: "https://test.com/api.php?id=1"
    },
    theme: {
      // theme configuration
    }
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>

Despite following the documentation, the parameter does not seem to be recognized or utilized by the flow. I've tried several variations and approaches, but the issue persists. How to properly pass parameters like "url" to the chat flow? or let me know if there's a different method to achieve this?
What I tried:
Initial setup:
Embedded the Flowise chat using the provided script.
Passed the url parameter via chatflowConfig as shown in the code snippet.
Parameter variations:
Tried different variations of the parameter names and values.
Tested with other parameters in chatflowConfig.
Expected outcome:
I expected the flow to recognize and utilize the url parameter to direct the API node to the specified endpoint https://test.com/api.php?id=1.
Actual result:
The flow completely ignored the url parameter and did not direct the API node to the specified endpoint. None of the variations I tried had any effect.

I'm hoping this will help you, or someone else who's stuck on this. I had the same issue and it took me quite a while to work it out. There are two ways of using a custom variable from an embedded chatbot:
in the client, use something like:
import Chatbot from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flowise-embed/dist/web.js"
Chatbot.init({
    chatflowid: "8a1a8b2e-101a-9500-a586-7dbd7f4d8e4c",
    apiHost: "https://flowisehost.com",
    chatflowConfig: {
      vars: {
        apiKey: "TEST_KEY"
      }
    }
});


in your flow, add a custom tool and get a handle on the variable, like so:
const myVar = $vars.apiKey;
return myVar;


Add the custom tool to a flow and tell your tool agent to use it. This worked for me, hope it helps.

you can reference the variable in any node directly (e.g. a system prompt), using {{$vars.apiKey}}. In this case, you don't even need a custom tool.

